# Start loop from half if array is odd in java

Tags: java, loops

I have a problem like in tittle, i want to make loop for for array with odd elements,

Ex. [ 5 , 5 , 3 , 7] in this way program will take 5+5 for left sum (array.lenght /2) and 3+7 for right sum. After all i want to compare them.

Problem is when the array looks like [ 5 , 5 , 3 ] in that way i cannot make array.lenght/2

And the question is what can i do?

```
    int rightSum = 0;
    int leftSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
        leftSum += array[i];
    }
    if (array.length % 2 == 0) {
        for (int i = array.length / 2; i < array.length; i++) {
            rightSum += array[i];
        }
    } else {

    }

    return leftSum == rightSum;
}
```

Comment: For the array with odd elements, do you want it to include the middle element or not?

Comment: Could you, please, secribe the *initial problem*? You compute `rightSum` and `leftSum` then compare them...

Comment: i wanted to compare both sides of array, if they are equal then return, about middle element i wanted to divide this element by 2 or take to one of side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code, you can remove your if-else clause and have you loops like below (having the middle element ignored):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
    leftSum += array[i];
}
for (int i = array.length - 1; i > array.length/2; i--) {
   rightSum += array[i];
}
```

If you want your middle element to be added to the left side, modify the condition on the first loop to *'i **<=** array.length / 2'*; if you want the middle element added to the right side, modify the condition in your second loop to *'i **>=** array.length/2'*

I just fixed your code, but there is a better way to code this. I guess you are new to coding, Patryk, so try writing some automated tests for the code and refactor, to increase its quality. Happy learning.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, yes i saw that you fixed and Thank you once again, as you can see it's the begining of my journey and i tried to learn by mysefl but sometimes i approach "the wall".
so if I add in second loop 'i > array.length/2'  it will take into account odd array ?

Comment: I suggest you try and see for yourself :) the best way to learn is trial and error ! also always try to understand the logic behind the code , and write unit tests to validate behavior in all cases, catching the edge cases is always hardest part

Comment: @PatrykSzymańczyk read the second paragraph in this answer and play with = (equal sign) and as @ OrrBenyamini said, try and check the outputs, so you'll have a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can do it in a single loop. Simply iterate halfway thru and sum the appropriate values from left and right.  If the array is of odd length, the middle value is ignored.

Note that if you change the conditional to include the middle value, it will simply be added to both side sums.  So there is really no point in it.

```
public static boolean halfSums(int[] arr) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length/2; i++) {
        left += arr[i];
        right+= arr[arr.length-i-1];
    }
    return left == right;
}
```